# GatsbyJs - make ImageSharp from multiple images referenced in csv

Tags: gatsby

Using `gatsby-transformer-csv` and `gatsby-transformer-sharp`

given a CSV file with one cell that has multiple images (with a local path) referenced, how can I get them to be processed by imageSharp?

```
id,slug,images
615,prime-click-solid-2,./images/products/PC-019-S1.png, ./images/products/PC-019-S-1.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, I think you'd have to do a lot of manual work here.

First, since values are separated by comma, you should group the images together:

```
id,slug,images
                         v                        v
615,prime-click-solid-2, "./img-1.png, ./img-2.png"
```

Then you can use `createSchemaCustomization` hook in gatsby-node to...

0. intercept the `images` field
1. extracts the paths from the original value, `./img-1.png, ./img-2.png`
2. create a correct absolute path for each of your image
3. query those images in Gatsby's database
4. return the images

I have a bit of downtime, so I ended up creating a small example.

Directory structure:

```
<root>
  |--content
  |     |
  |     |--images
  |     |     |--img-1.png
  |     |     `--img-2.png
  |     |     
  |     `--data.csv
  |
  `--gatsby-node.js
```

data.csv content

```
id,images
hello,"./images/287.jpg, ./images/288.jpg"
```

Custom gatsby hook

```js
// gatsby-node.js

const path = require('path')

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions

  const types = schema.buildObjectType({
    name: 'DataCsv', // Gatsby create name based on your csv file name. Yours will be different — you can find your CSV type name in localhost:8000/___graphql
    interfaces: ['Node'],
    extensions: {
      infer: true,
    },
    fields: {
      images: {
        type: '[File]', // important. We're saying DataCsv.images will return an array of File, instead of a string as inferred by default.
        resolve: async (src, args, context, info) => {
          const { fieldName } = info
          const paths = src[fieldName]
          const imagePaths = paths.split(',').map(str => str.trim())

          const absolutePaths = imagePaths.map(imagePath => {
            return path.join(__dirname, 'content', imagePath)
          })

          const fileNodes = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            type: 'File',
            query: {
              filter: {
                absolutePath: {
                  in: absolutePaths
                }
              }
            }
          })

          return fileNodes
        }
      }
    }
  })

  createTypes(types)
}
```

Then, you can query the images:

```
  query Images {
    dataCsv {
      images {
        childImageSharp {
          original {
            src
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can see the example & adapt as needed here:
https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-csv-multi-images-example

### Resources

You can learn more about this hook in the [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/), but it's a bit dry.

I've also written a tutorial [on the topic here](https://www.byderek.com/post/a-stackoverflow-question--a-use-case-for-gatsbys-field-extension).

Hope it's helpful!

**Edit** Gatsby has since made `runQuery` asynchronous (Jul 2020), the answer has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to do here can be broken down to two steps:

- Parse the CSV into an array of nodes, with each node containing an array of image URLs.
- Iterate over these nodes at build time, and transform every URL in each node's URL array into an `imageSharp` node.

---

One way to approach this<sup>*</sup> would be to:

- [Configure `gatsby-transformer-csv`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-csv/#parsing-algorithm) in your `gatsby-config` to give your CSV nodes a custom name.
- Override `onCreateNode` in `gatsby-node`, add a conditional to trigger when your CSV nodes are created, extract the array of image URLs from the node, and iterate over those to create the `imageSharp` nodes from the filesystem.

Alternatively, you may be able to get by without the second step if you just parse out the image paths, then pass those into a `file` GraphQL query with `file(relativePath: $path) { childImageSharp { /* ... */ }` or similar, as outlined [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/?=gatsby-image#how-to-use) for example. Keep in mind that dynamic queries in Gatsby can only be used in top-level "page" components, whereas static queries can be used anywhere.

<sup>*</sup>There may be better ways! As mentioned above, it's hard to say what the "best" solution is without knowing more about your use-case. Gatsby is very flexible with how you manage your data.